# Interpreting the covariate p-values in a multivariate generalized linear model?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, categorical-encoding

If a covariate in a GLM is "significant" does that mean it is significantly different from the base case (the group not shown)?

Say we have three groups, Control, Exp1, Exp2. We are injecting a series of current steps into the cells of each group and measuring the resulting "spikes" (patch clamp experiment for those interested). I was advised to compare the groups by building a GLM using the groups and currents to determine if the groups were different.
The resulting table provides the coefficient estimates, t values, p values etc. for Intercept, Current, Exp1, Exp2, and the interactions between Exp1/2 and current (using `R`, see bottom for code to reproduce):

```
    summary(glm(formula = spikes ~ current * groups, 
    family = gaussian, data = df))
    # ...
```

Coefficients:

|  | Estimate | Std. Error | t value | p value |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 9.170e-01 | 6.305e-02 | 14.544 | 2.12e-13 | *** |
| current | 1.477e-01 | 1.016e-02 | 14.538 | 2.14e-13 | *** |
| groupsExp1 | -5.000e-02 | 8.916e-02 | -0.561 | 0.580151 |  |
| groupsExp2 | -4.000e-01 | 8.916e-02 | -4.486 | 0.000153 | *** |
| current:groupsExp1 | -2.564e-17 | 1.437e-02 | 0.000 | 1.000000 |  |
| current:groupsExp2 | -4.754e-17 | 1.437e-02 | 0.000 | 1.000000 |  |

I am struggling to interpret the p values in the context of the model.
I was told by a colleague to interpret the significant `groupsExp2` covariate as meaning "Exp2 is significantly different from control", and the non significant `groupsExp1` meaning that it is not significantly different from control (since control is left out of the output and is the base case?). Most of what I have learned about GLMs/LMs is related to gauging how well some variable predicts an output, and whether combining them predicts the output better/worse/not differently than without. Interpreting them in a NHST framework seems wrong to me...
Is this interpretation **Exp2 is significantly different than Control** correct?

R Code to generate:

```
    mkdata <- function() {
      current <- c(rep(1:10), rep(1:10), rep(1:10))
      groups <- c(rep("Control", 10), rep("Exp1", 10), rep("Exp2", 10))
      spikes <- c(log(rep(3:12)) - 0.2, log(rep(3:12)) - 0.25, log(rep(3:12)) - 0.6)
      data.frame(current, groups, spikes)
      }
    df <- mkdata()
    spikes.glm <- glm(spikes ~ current*groups, data = df, family = gaussian)
    summary(spikes.glm)
```